# Regex validate either empty or only letters

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate an input to be either empty or only contain letters. The letter part I got figured out at ^[a-zA-Z]+$ . How can I accept the input if it's empty too?

Answer (score 10):

Try changing your `+` to a `*`, as in this pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z]*$
```

This will match zero or more Latin letters, so it will accept an empty string as well.

For international support, you might also want to consider:

```
^\p{L}*$
```

This will match zero or more letters in any Unicode language.

Comment: And if you need additional Unicode letters, you can use `^\p{IsAlphabetic}*$`.